# Best way of logging multiple values in a Scala / Akka class

Tags: scala, logging, akka, reactive-programming, actor

I'm in a situation where I need to log multiple values in an Akka (Scala) project to a single entry. Consider the following pseudocode, comments show where I have the information needed for the log entry.

```
def buildUrl() {
    // Item 1: Log url parameters
    val a = getMeSth(...)
    stuff(a);
}

def fetchUrl() {
    // Item 2: Log start time
    fetchAndHitAndRun(buildUrl())
}

def parseResponse() {
    // Item 3, 4, 5 ... 6: Log values from response
    // Item 7: Log time taken
    parseRsp(fetchUrl());
}
```

I need multiple values from multiple functions in order to build my logging model. How can I achieve that in Scala? Filling a class with the information seems to be a wrong approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to log all those values as a single event. Please correct me if you are wrong.

The most simple approach would be to return the values you need from the inner functions.

```
def buildUrl() {
    // Item 1: Log url parameters
    val a = getMeSth(...)
    val urlParameters = ???
    (stuff(a), urlParameters)
}

def fetchUrl() {
    val (stuff, urlParameters) = buildUrl()
    // Item 2: Log start time
    val startTime = ???
    (fetchAndHitAndRun(stuff), urlParameters, startTime)
}
```

... and so for each item you need.

Another is to use an actor that collects all the items it needs and then logs the entry.

```
class TransactionLogger extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive = append(Map.empty)
  def append(entries: Map[String, Any] = {
    case Append(key, value) => 
      context become append(entries + (key -> value))
    case Log =>
      log.info("{}", entries)
      context stop self 
 }
}
```

So for each transaction you create this actor and then you send it stuff

```
val logger = system.actorOf(Props[TransactionLogger], transactionId)
logger ! Append("startTime", startTime)
logger ! Append("somethingElse", ???)
```

And when you are ready to flush it out

```
logger ! Log
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I went with the Actor way, but planned some restructuring of the application to make it fit my new requirement.